# Split-split-plot ANOVA analysis with missing values - correct model with three factors?

Tags: r, anova, split-plot

I am having trouble figuring out if my ANOVA model is correct. I am analyzing a split-split plot greenhouse study with shade as the main factor (n = 3 treatments), site as the sub-plot factor (n = 3 treatments), and litter as the sub-sub-plot factor (n = 2 treatments). This was replicated five times for a total of 90 plots. Unfortunately, 20 plots died throughout the experiment so I ran the analysis with 70 height values and 20 NAs. The depdendent variable measured was height. What I want to know is whether or not height was affected by shade, site, or litter, or any combination thereof.

Sample data:

```r
       plot rep shade site litter height
451     1     1     0   SC      Y     NA
452     2     1     0  TON      Y    5.8
453     3     1     0  TON      N    4.4
454     4     1     0   SC      N    6.3
455     5     1     0   GC      Y     NA
456     6     1     0   GC      N    3.4
457     7     2     1   GC      Y    7.2
458     8     2     1  TON      Y    6.8
459     9     2     1   SC      Y    6.6
460    10     2     1   GC      N    7.0
461    11     2     1   SC      N    6.9
462    12     2     1  TON      N    7.3
463    13     3     0   SC      Y    6.5
464    14     3     0  TON      Y    5.9
465    15     3     0  TON      N    7.3
466    16     3     0   GC      Y    6.8
467    17     3     0   SC      N     NA
468    18     3     0   GC      N    7.5
469    19     4     1  TON      Y    8.8
```

My current model is as follows:

```r
aovout <- aov(height ~  rep + shade*site*litter + Error(rep/shade/site), data=df)
summary(aovout)
```

but this results in the following warning message:

```
In aov(y ~ block + shade * site * litter + Error(block/shade/site),  :
  Error() model is singular
```

I'm still able to run `summary(aov)` but I am hesitant to interpret the results because of the error message. Is this because the model is unbalanced because of the NAs? I'm not even sure I am running the correct model for what I want to determine.